# Placing the :before-value in the same way as a list-item is placed?

Tags: css

I'm using counters to setup a special type of counting of lists, it's for a legal form.

```
li{
    list-style: none;
}

>ol {
    counter-reset: mainlist;
}

>ol>li{
    counter-reset: sublist;
}

>ol>li:before{
    counter-increment: mainlist;
    content: counter(mainlist) ". ";
}

>ol>li>ol>li:before{
    counter-increment: sublist;
    content: counter(mainlist) "." counter(sublist) " ";
}
```

This works fine, but I want the numbering to be to the left of the text column, not the way it looks now.

```
1.1
this is how it looks now


1.1 this is how it looks if I add inline
next row will start here.


1.1 I want it to look this.
    the next row starts here 
    and it's a lot easier to find the numbers
```

I tried using text-indent aswell, but it didn't work because the width of the different letters are different.

Comment: Can you include a small chunk of the html for the list

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to add `display:flex` to the `li` and you get this layout:

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: mainlist;
}

ol>li {
  counter-reset: sublist;
}

ol>li:before {
  counter-increment: mainlist;
  content: counter(mainlist) ". ";
}

ol>li>ol>li {
  display: flex;
}

ol>li>ol>li:before {
  counter-increment: sublist;
  content: counter(mainlist) "." counter(sublist) " ";
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbbb 
    <ol>
      <li>aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa </li>
      <li>bbbbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbbb</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

And if you want this behavior to be on the parent li, you need to use flex on parent li also with some HTML/CSS adjustement:

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
  counter-reset: mainlist;
  counter-reset: sublist;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ol>li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ol>li>span {
  flex: 1;
}

ol>li>ol {
  flex: 100%;
}

ol > li:before {
  counter-increment: mainlist;
  content: counter(mainlist) ". ";
  margin-right: 5px;
}

ol>li>ol>li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

ol > li > ol > li:before {
  counter-increment: sublist;
  content: counter(mainlist) "." counter(sublist) " ";
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><span>aaaaaa</span></li>
  <li><span>bbbbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbbb</span>
    <ol>
      <li>aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa </li>
      <li>bbbbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbbb</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><span>bbbbbbb bbbbbbb bbbbbbb</span>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in css table-layout by adding `display: table-row;` to the `li` and `display: table-cell;` to the `li:before`

The benefit of table cell is the cells will expand all the same no matter how large the number gets, i.e.

```
  1.1 This will line up with
1.125 This
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/curthusting/pen/2e024696ae7a9b8a32b798f40d90ff7e?editors=1100)

```css
body {
    counter-reset: mainlist;
    counter-reset: sublist;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
    display: table-row;
}

ol>li:before{
    counter-increment: mainlist;
    content: counter(mainlist) ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 6px;
}

ol>li>ol>li:before{
    counter-increment: sublist;
    content: counter(mainlist) "." counter(sublist) " ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    First Section
    <ol>
      <li>I want it to look this. the next row starts here and it's a lot easier to find the numbers</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```